# OpenLayers 3 - Bing maps won't load in Windows App

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, openlayers-3, windows

I'm trying to load Bing maps using OpenLayers 3 in a Windows application. However, i'm facing the following error:

```
APPHOST9601: Can’t load <https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/AerialWithLabels?uriScheme=https&include=ImageryProviders&key=Ao9wqOnCiDvABI4LnDdguzUE0lbF1PiAcDSYHkKdezCage1xuUXY2emXAuHzdOUX&jsonp=olc_9>. An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.
```

I've tried adding the following line to the ContentUriRules in the manifest without success:

```
<Rule Match="https://dev.virtualearth.net/*" Type="include" />
```

I do not want to load the OpenLayers map in an iframe, because then I have to use the postMessage function to pass data to the iframe from classes outside the iframe. Is there a workaround to get the Bing maps working?

Answer (score 0):

Without using an iframe, the Windows app will not let you to load any external script references. I recommend taking a look at using Apache Cordova which hosts everything in an iframe and also gives you access to the native features of the Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the issue by adding a function to the OL library that loads an url containing JSON data without using JSONP. Now the data is seen as JSON instead of Javascript (inherent to JSONP) and thus the security restrictions do not apply anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The loading time can be long for this request. I wonder if we could avoid making it every time the window is refreshed.

I also have a problems with stereographic projection but otherwise it's OK.